# WordPress Multisite wp-admin/ redirect loop but adding index.php works fine

Tags: multisite

Being quick, In my WordPress multisite installation, whenever I try to login to WP-ADMIN, default login method gives me `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` where URL ends with `/` but when I add some absolute URL like `index.php` or `plugins.php`, it works fine.

How to fix this?

Here is part of my wp-config.php:

```
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.example.org.au'); 
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1); 
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/'); 
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '');
define('COOKIEPATH', ''); 
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '');
```

Comment: Additionally I cannot load /wp-admin/network/*, receiving the same error.

Comment: Here is part of my wp-config.php: `define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.example.org.au');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '');
define('COOKIEPATH', '');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '');`

Comment: Please add also your .htaccess rules for the Multisite

Comment: Did you updated all the necessary URLs in the database? This tool might help: https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Comment: Also, check this article: https://tommcfarlin.com/resolving-the-wordpress-multisite-redirect-loop/